# Validating a phone number in Javascript using Java example as a base

Tags: java, javascript, validation

Currently i am validating the validation form for phone number using the following code in Java action, but i want to do this validation from javascript, can you guys please guide me.

```
String mvrUserPhone = mvrUser.getPhone();
        mvrUserPhone = mvrUserPhone.replaceAll("[+-]", "");
        if (!mvrUserPhone.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                long phoneNumber = Long.parseLong(mvrUserPhone);
                System.out.println(phoneNumber);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                errorMessage = errorMessage + "<br />- Invalid phone number.<br /> 
(Please enter phone number in xxx-xxx-xxxx format)";
                errorCount++;
            }
```

--
thanks

Comment: Are you aware that your method doesn't validate the format of the phone number at all? You should fix you Java validation (hint: regexes are useful here) before doing the same in JS.

Comment: the alphabets validation am doing from the javascript, but the symbols  "+" and "-" are not working some times.. so the "+" and "-" validation am doing from java.

Comment: You must always validate everything at server-side. JavaScript can be disabled or circumvented by the user. If you don't want junk data and incoherences in your database, don't ever trust the user, and validate everything at server-side. Validating at client-side is only an added bonus, but should not replace server-side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using javascript for phone number as a example (taken from http://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/phone-number-validation-using-jquery/):

```
function ValidatePhone() {
    var phoneRegExp = 
        /^((\+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([-\s\.])?((\(\d{1,4}\))|\d{1,4})(([-\s\.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}$/;
    var phoneVal = $("#txtPhone").val();
    var numbers = phoneVal.split("").length;
    if (10 <= numbers && numbers <= 20 && phoneRegExp.test(phoneVal)) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is regexp. There is tutorial how to Validate U.S Phone Numbers using JavaScript Regular expression.  http://www.zparacha.com/phone_number_regex/

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in [Jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), nice JS framework and extend it's validation methods.
Something like this to extend.

```
$.validator.addMethod( 
"phoneNumber",
function(value, element, params) {
    if(this.optional(element)){
        return true;
    }
    var phoneNumberPattern = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;  
    return phoneNumberPattern.test(value);
},
"Incorrect phone number."
);
```